# How to change the dimensions of a tikzpicture without making the font inconsistent with the rest of the document

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to reproduce this graph from a textbook using pgfplots:

[image]

The issue I am running in to is that I cannot find a way to stretch my tikzpicture horizontally in a visually appealing way - resizebox isn't cutting it.

Here's what I've got so far, please pardon it not being the most "minimal", I felt that the question would be easier to understand if my "MWE" resembled the diagram I'm trying to mimic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    trig format=deg,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
standard,
xmin=-4, xmax=10,
xtick={-3.14159*3/2,-3.14159,-3.14159/2,3.14159/2,3.14159,3.14159*3/2,3.14159*2,3.14159*5/2,3.14159*3,3.14159*7/2}, ytick={-1,1},
xticklabels={}, yticklabels={$-1$,$1$},
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},]
\addplot[domain=-5:11,samples=300] {cos(deg(x))};
\node[above] at (-3.14159,0) {$-\pi$};
\node[above] at (3.14159,0) {$\pi$};
\node[above] at (3.14159*3,0) {$3\pi$};
\node[below] at (-3.14159/2,0) {$-\frac{\pi}{2}$};
\node[below] at (3.14159/2,0) {$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
\node[below] at (3.14159*3/2,0) {$\frac{3\pi}{2}$};
\node[below] at (3.14159*2,0) {$2\pi$};
\node[below] at (3.14159*5/2,0) {$\frac{5\pi}{2}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this produces a square diagram:

[image]

How can I get my diagram to have the same dimensions as the one in the book? How can I stretch it horizontally without using a font destroying operation like resizebox?

Thank you  very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the `width` and `height` options of `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    trig format=deg,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    },
    width=.96\linewidth,
    height=2.5cm,
    scale only axis=true
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
standard,
xmin=-4, xmax=10,
xtick={-3.14159*3/2,-3.14159,-3.14159/2,3.14159/2,3.14159,3.14159*3/2,3.14159*2,3.14159*5/2,3.14159*3,3.14159*7/2}, ytick={-1,1},
xticklabels={}, yticklabels={$-1$,$1$},
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},]
\addplot[domain=-5:11,samples=300] {cos(deg(x))};
\node[above] at (-3.14159,0) {$-\pi$};
\node[above] at (3.14159,0) {$\pi$};
\node[above] at (3.14159*3,0) {$3\pi$};
\node[below] at (-3.14159/2,0) {$-\frac{\pi}{2}$};
\node[below] at (3.14159/2,0) {$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
\node[below] at (3.14159*3/2,0) {$\frac{3\pi}{2}$};
\node[below] at (3.14159*2,0) {$2\pi$};
\node[below] at (3.14159*5/2,0) {$\frac{5\pi}{2}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! I've always wanted to know how to do this. Will accept in 7 minutes when allowed :).

Comment: @Pseudonym123 You're welcome!